# OpenGL ES 2.0 Doesn't draw anything with glGetError 0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to color every vertex of my triangle differently.When I compiled the code, it hadn't drawn anything, so i used the glGetError() function.The function returns 0,which means there are no errors, but it still doesn't draw anything. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong.Here is my GLsurfaceView  class, and my drawing class.

```
     @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0f,0,0,0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        float ratio=(float) width/(float)height;
        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 0.1f, 500);
    }
    public int x=0;
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1.78f, 0, 0, 1, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        //GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glDraw draw =new glDraw();
        Matrix.translateM(mMVPMatrix,0,0,0,0);
        draw.drawTriangle(mMVPMatrix,new float[]{ 1,0,0,1f});
        Matrix.rotateM(mMVPMatrix,0,x,0,1,0);
        Matrix.translateM(mMVPMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        draw.drawTriangle(mMVPMatrix,new float[]{1,1,0,0.5f});
        x++;
    }
    public class glDraw {
        private float[] vertecies={
                0.0f,2.0f,0.0f,
                1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,
               -1.0f,0.0f,0.0f
        };
        private float[] colors={
                1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.5f,
                0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.5f,
                0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.5f
        };
        private short[] indicies={0,1,2};

    private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;
    private final String vertexShaderCode=
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;"+
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;"+
            "attribute vec4 a_Color;"+
            "varying vec4 v_Color;"+
            "void main(){"+
            "   v_Color=a_Color;"+
            "   gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;"+
            "   gl_PointSize=10.0;"+
            "}";
    private final String fragmentShaderCode=
            "precision mediump float;"+
            "varying vec4 v_Color;"+
            "void main(){"+
            "   gl_FragColor=v_Color;"+
            "}";
    private int ShaderProgram;
    public static int glLoadShader(int Type,String shaderCode){
        int shader=GLES20.glCreateShader(Type);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        return shader;
    }
    private int matrixHandle;
    public glDraw(){
        ByteBuffer vbb= ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertecies.length*4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer=vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertecies);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer cbb= ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        colorBuffer=cbb.asFloatBuffer();
        colorBuffer.put(colors);
        colorBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader=glLoadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader=glLoadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,fragmentShaderCode);
        ShaderProgram=GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(ShaderProgram);
    }
    public void drawTriangle(float[] mvpMatrix,float[] color){
        GLES20.glUseProgram(ShaderProgram);
        int PositionAttrib = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(ShaderProgram, "vPosition");
        int ColorAttrib = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(ShaderProgram,"a_Color");

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(PositionAttrib, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(PositionAttrib);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(ColorAttrib, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, colorBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(ColorAttrib);
        Integer a=GLES20.glGetError();
        Log.e("ERROR:",a.toString());
        matrixHandle= GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProgram,"uMVPMatrix");
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,0,vertecies.length/3);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(PositionAttrib);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try adding _glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)_ to see your vertex order is correct and not causing the issue with rendering.

Comment: I've tryed it but it still not work.

Comment: glDraw draw =new glDraw(); must not be in  onDrawFrame() which is called every 18ms

Comment: I tried it. Stil nothing. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile and link your shader code only once. However, you call the incomplete code every frame.

Take out this code.

```
int vertexShader=glLoadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader=glLoadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,fragmentShaderCode);
    ShaderProgram=GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    GLES20.glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, vertexShader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(ShaderProgram);
```

Follow this code below.

```
    public int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource) {
    int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
    int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);

    int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    if (program != 0) {
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
        int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
        if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ");
            Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
            program = 0;
        }
    }
    return program;
}

private int loadShader(int shaderType, String source) {
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
        if (shader != 0) {
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
            int[] compiled = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
            if (compiled[0] == 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not compile shader " + shaderType + ":");
                Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
                shader = 0;
            }
        }
        return shader;
}
```

Keep in mind that you need to call this once before rendering objects